# Get SurfaceTexture in android instrumented tests

Tags: android, android-camera2, instrumented-test

As in title, I am looking way to get or create SurfaceTexture, which I can pass to CaptureSession(in Camera2 API). Is there a chance to create programatically virtual TextureView, then attach it to virtual WindowManager, and then get Surface, and then pass it to CaptureSession?  Or maybe easier way to just create TextureView which is available? In instrumented tests.